# Поменять местами рандомные пары символов в файле на Cи

Tags: c, массивы

Есть задача N-количество раз переставить рандомные пары символов в файле. Позиции пар символов задаются рандомом. Количество перестановок задается пользователем.

1 вариант. Открыть 1 файл на чтение и на запись. Далее сформировать массив с рандомными позициями, отсортировать его в порядке возрастания. Затем посимвольньно записывать в файл, пока не дойдем до нужной позиции. Когда доходим до позиции, меняем местами, записываем в этот же файл и идем дальше.

2 вариант. Записать каждый символ в массив. Ну и далее все понятно.

Подскажите, может есть другой вариант решения задачи получше и что почитать по этой теме?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему вас не применить `fseek`? Стали на первое место, считали, стали на второе, считали в другую переменную, перезаписали новыми значениями первое и второе места, и пошли к следующей паре?

Comment: Про `fseek` знаю. А как сделать перезапись новыми значениями?

Comment: Ну просто пусть позиции p1 и p2. Переменные c1, c2. Делаете `fseek(p1)` (я не пишу все параметры, места мало.... разберетесь), `fread(&c1)`, `fseek(p2)`,`fread(&c2)`, `fseek(p1)`, `fwrite(&c2)`, `fseek(p2)`, `fwrite(&c1)`. Вот и все.

Comment: Спасибо. Функция `fwrite` прошла мимо меня.